# Activating Apache Felix HTTP bundle within Karaf

Tags: java, jetty, apache-karaf, apache-felix

We are running `apache-karaf-4.2.0` on an internal network that is not connected to the internet. We are trying to get an HTTP server running within Karaf and we decided to use `org.apache.felix.http.bundle-3.0.0.jar` since it contains everything we need in one jar (as opposed to bringing back everything listed in the `http` feature within Karaf).

Here are my steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Download a copy of `apache-karaf-4.2.0.tar.gz` and untar it
2. Download a copy of `org.apache.felix.http.bundle-3.0.0.jar`
3. cd into `apache-karaf-4.2.0`
4. `mkdir -p system/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.http.bundle/3.0.0/`
5. Copy `org.apache.felix.http.bundle-3.0.0.jar` into the directory you just
   created
6. Open
   `system/org/apache/karaf/features/standard/4.2.0/standard-4.2.0-features.xml`
7. At the bottom, before `<feature name="standard"...>` add the following
   lines (see below since I cannot embed it into this list):
8. Open `etc/custom.properties`
9. Add the following line to the bottom: `org.apache.felix.jettyEnabled =
   true`
10. Execute `./bin/karaf`
11. At the karaf prompt type: `feature:install felix-http`

And here's what the XML should look like in the `standard-4.2.0-features.xml` file:

```
<feature name="felix-http" description="Apache Felix HTTP Bundle" version="4.2.0">
    <bundle>mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.http.bundle/3.0.0</bundle>
    <config name="org.apache.felix.http">
        org.osgi.service.http.port=8888
    </config>
</feature>
```

If I understand the `IncompatibleClassChangeError` it means *something* was compiled with an older version of *something else*. I'm assuming that *something else* is `jetty` but nothing else is providing it. So I'm very confused.

If anyone has any thoughts on how to continue to debug and/or fix this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: are you sure there isn't another jetty instance running?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm pretty sure :) As I said in the original post, I only have the listed features installed and I've gone through them and none of them appear to be providing anything related to Jetty.